# Is the Singleton Pattern suitable for a VB.Net tray app without the Application Framework?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a Windows Tray App which doesn't use the Application Framework. The startup object is a module sub, which makes calls to a class to create the app icon directly in the tray without opening any forms.

I've just started reading about the Singleton Pattern, with the intention of making the app single-instance. This seems to be the way it should be done, but...appearance and reality are not the same. What looks good may not be.

- Is singleton the best way to make a tray app single-instance?
- Are there other ways that should be considered?
- Are there any common problems that arise when developing with these ways?

Comment: The typical way to restrict to a single instance is to use a mutex. I'm not sure why you would need to go through all the work of implementing a singleton to avoid writing five or six lines of code.

Comment: Starting from Sub Main doesnt rule out using the VB App Framework

Comment: Although it occurs in many design books, the singleton to me is a clear anti-pattern. There *are*  situations where it is feasible but they are very rare. So why do you want to use it? Do you want to make sure that your app is started only once?

Comment: I'm creating a tray app that starts directly to the tray, without first opening any forms hidden or otherwise. But tray apps should be single-instance. The technique is described here, but this does not cover the single instance issues: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75822/Create-a-System-Tray-Application-in-VB-NET

Comment: Just as an aside, there's no such thing as a "tray app".  You can have an application and it can put an icon in the system tray but otherwise there is nothing special about it.  Sorry, had to get that off my chest.  Nothing to see here.

Comment: No, that was informative. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of what a singleton is that is leading you astray. A singleton is a class that enforces that there can only ever be one instance of the class throughout the lifetime of an application.

The singleton pattern doesn't apply to applications as a whole.

If you require that the application restrict itself to only allow one instance to be running at any given time then, what I have done in the past is to have your app check the running processes on the computer as soon as it starts. If it finds any that have the same name as what your app is called then the second instance stops itself.

- The flaw with this approach is that there is nothing to say that some external application can't have the same name as your application(however unlikely that may be)

I've never really looked into it beyond that so I can't comment on any other viable options.

Comment: Mike Obrien, How do you feel about checking more than just the process name of the app, and going further to check things like the version & copyright, or some other signature(s), to ensure it's really the same app? Thank you for your response; I see now my misunderstanding. When I realized the singleton approach was just for a single class, I said "D'oh!" out loud like Homer Simpson. =-)

Comment: Singletons are tricky animals, they seem to lend themselves to a wide variety of problems but knowing when to use them is arguably harder than knowing how to use them. As for the approach I mentioned, the more checks you can throw in to verify whats running is actually yours  will obviously make the approach more reliable. Getting the process info is very easy and there are a bunch of properties that can be checked.